# No se hace transparente el navbar de bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

No se me hace transparente el Navbar de bootstrap 4, intento colocandole una clase llamada al navbar llamada `<nav class="my-navbar">`
Y quitarle en el css el color de este modo :

```
.my-navbar{
border:0px;
border-radius: 0px;
background:none;
}
```

y no se le quita el color que viene por defecto el bootstrap 4.

Codigo del navbar

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light my-navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">My gifts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: una ayuda mira esto [nav transparente](https://www.codeply.com/go/6PLav7dBbz/bootstrap-4-navbar-transparent-background-image)

Comment: El nav bar ya trae por defecto bg-transparent, podrías probarlo
Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer, no necesitas agregar ningún estilo personalizado para remover el color de fondo, simplemente quita la clase `bg-light` de `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light my-navbar">`, y tu estilo personalizado:

```css
.my-navbar {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light my-navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">My gifts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    </div>
```